# Kubernetes Deployed nginx app is not rendering web content

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes, kubectl

I am trying to deploy nginx image from docker hub to kubernetes cluster.

This is the steps I did -

```
docker pull nginx
kubectl run nginx --image=nginx --port=8080 --image-pull-policy=IfNotPresent
kubectl expose deployment nginx --type=LoadBalancer --port=80 --target-port=8080 --name=nginx

xxx@cloudshell:~ (involuted-ratio-227118)$ kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP    PORT(S)        AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP      10.51.240.1     <none>         443/TCP        2d
nginx        LoadBalancer   10.51.252.202   34.73.115.78   80:30355/TCP   8m
nginx-http   ClusterIP      10.51.254.159   <none>         80/TCP         1d
```

Below is the error displayed on accessing external endpoint URL -

The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: http://34.73.115.78/

Connection to 34.73.115.78 failed.
The system returned: (111) Connection refused
The remote host or network may be down. Please try the request again.
Your cache administrator is webmaster.

But I see nginx deployed and also service endpoint showing without any errors in kubernetes-dashboard. I even checked nginx pod logs and this is what is displayed -
The selected container has not logged any messages yet.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nginx run in port `80`. But you are trying to connect in port `8080`. That's why you are getting error. Try this instead:

```
kubectl run nginx --image=nginx --port=80 --image-pull-policy=IfNotPresent

kubectl expose deployment nginx --type=LoadBalancer --port=80 --target-port=80 --name=nginx
```